# Code=-1016 "The `parameters` argument is not valid JSON." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The `parameters` argument is not valid JSON.}

Tags: swift, alamofire, afnetworking-3

I am cleaning up some code and trying to put a serverRequest in my NSManagedObject class. The exact same function works perfectly in the UIViewController it was originally written in, however, when I call it in the CoreData object file I get the following Error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.request Code=-1016 "The `parameters` argument is not valid JSON." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The `parameters` argument is not valid JSON.}
```

I printed my 'parameters' in the original case as well as the new and they are EXACTLY the same. I am successfully hitting other endpoints I have setup in this CoreData object class, but this one for some reason is failing.

Any ideas?

#### Successful: uploading question packet ChecklistTABLEVIEW.swift

```
["answers": ["each": <_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStoragePs9AnyObject__ 0x604000c551b0>(
{
    answerString = "";
    "assigned_emails" =     (
        "email@email.com"
    );
    "checklist_id" = 186;
    questionId = 4274;
    rating = "";
    "report_time" = "2018-09-13 19:40:21 +0000";
},
{
    answerString = "";
    "assigned_emails" =     (
        "email@email.com"
    );
    "checklist_id" = 186;
    questionId = 293112;
    rating = "";
    "report_time" = "2018-09-13 19:40:21 +0000";
    selected =     (
    );
}
)
, "checklist_id": 186], "user": ["authentication_token": "TOKEN", "email": "email@email.com"], "count": 2]
```

#### Unsuccessful: uploading question packet CHECKLIST.swift

```
["answers": ["each": <_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStoragePs9AnyObject__ 0x600000c57ee0>(
{
    answerString = "";
    "assigned_emails" =     (
        "email@email.com"
    );
    "checklist_id" = 186;
    questionId = 4274;
    rating = "";
    "report_time" = "2018-09-13 19:40:21 +0000";
},
{
    answerString = "";
    "assigned_emails" =     (
        "email@email.com"
    );
    "checklist_id" = 186;
    questionId = 293112;
    rating = "";
    "report_time" = "2018-09-13 19:40:21 +0000";
    selected =     (
    );
}
)
, "checklist_id": 186], "user": ["authentication_token": "TOKEN", "email": "email@email.com"], "count": 2]
```

Those parameters are the exact same in the **Successful** and **Unsuccessful** cases, they are just called from different files. Why would one get an serialization error from **AFNetworking**?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  I had a date in my parameters and had to convert it to a String.

I used this code to find the specific issue.

```
if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(params)
{
    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    {
        print("JSON data object is: \(data)")
    }
}            
else
{
    do
    {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        print("JSON data object is: \(data)")
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("no  bueno: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Voted for taking the time to post a solution when you found it.